# How to decrypt an encrypted ASCII binary value?

Tags: c, clion

So as an assignment we've got a code that can decrypt and encrypt ASCII values.
When giving the value `0` to `set_cipher` you can decrypt the value of an ASCII binary, for example:

If we take the ASCII binary value of `H` with the `char message` set to

`char message[] = {'H', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o'};` 
 and the`byte secret_str[]` set to `byte secret_str[] = {0b01001000};`. we get the message `H`

The assignment in question gives us 3 encrypted values, `0b11100110 0b11100111 0b11101000`these values respectively should give `a b c` as the decrypted value. to do this you will have to debug around to find which cipher was used to decrypt said `a b c`.

I've been trying to debug the code around and yet I still did not find which cipher value was set to encrypt those letters.
For example in the code below I want to decrypt

`byte secret_str[] = 0b11100110`

What I get once I debug this piece of code is the value `230`, 230 in the ASCII table gives the character `µ`. The problem now is, you already know that the character which you should get is `a`.

The ASCII value of the letter `a` is `97`, so there is a difference of `133`between those 2 values.

After steadily increasing the cipher myself I've seen that once you set `set_cipher(0)`to `set_cipher(123)` you get `a` once you run the code.

Is there someone who can explain this process to me?

the code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "include/utils.h"

int cipher = CIPHER_DEFAULT_VALUE;

int get_cipher() {
return cipher;
}

void set_cipher(int value) {
    cipher = value;
 }

char byte_to_char(byte input) {
     char output = (char)(input + get_cipher());
     return output;
 }

char char_to_byte(char input) {
     byte output = (byte)(input - get_cipher());
     return output;
 }

void cipher_decrypt(char * output, byte *secret_str, int secret_length) {
     int i;

for (i = 0; i < secret_length; i++) {
    byte byteValue = secret_str[i];
    char character = byte_to_char(byteValue);
    output[i] = character;
}
}

void cipher_encrypt(byte * output, char *str, int str_length) {
    int i;

for (i = 0; i < str_length; i++) {
    char character = str[i];
    byte byteValue = char_to_byte(character);
    output[i] = byteValue;
}
}

void print_byte_array(byte secret_str[], int secret_length) {
    int i;

for (i = 0; i < secret_length; i++) {
    printf("0b" BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN " ", BYTE_TO_BINARY(secret_str[i]));
}
printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    set_cipher(0);

/*
 * This example shows how a message can be encrypted!
 * Required:    A message in a char array (message[])
 *              Length of message (calculated automatically)
 *              Byte-array, stores the encrypted message so make sure it's big enough!
 *
 * 'string_to_bytes' encrypts your message, output will be stored in first argument (secret_output)
 *
 * The 'print_byte_array'-method prints the encrypted message in binary format!
 * This you can use for the decryption.
 */
char message[] = {'H', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
int message_length = sizeof(message) / sizeof(message[0]);
byte secret_output[100] = {0};

cipher_encrypt(&secret_output, message, message_length);
print_byte_array(secret_output, message_length);


/*
 * This example shows how a message can be decrypted!
 * Required:    A encrypted message
 *              Length of message (calculated automatically)
 *              Char-array with enough space for the message.
 *
 * 'bytes_to_string' decrypts your message, the message will be stores in 'output_str'.
 * To decrypt, your offset number must be the same as used when encrypting the message.
 *
 * To define an array of bytes, you have to append 0b in front of the 1's and 0's, example:
 *  00111100 will become 0b00111100
 *  01010101 will become 0b01010101
 *
 */

byte secret_str[] = { 0b11100110};
char output_str[200] = {};
int secret_length = sizeof(secret_str) / sizeof(secret_str[0]);

cipher_decrypt(&output_str, secret_str, secret_length);
printf("Geheim: %s \n", output_str);
return 0;
}
```

Is there a logical explanation on how the number 123 can be attained ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging, you can see the output of the encrypted binary. The value you get is `-26` and the value of the letter we need is `97`. The difference between these two number is the number we need, which is `123`. So that is the cipher which was used to encrypt the letters `abc`